# How to convert string of format ddmmyyyy to yymmdd

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, formatting

I am trying to convert a few strings to a specific format. So for example:

- ddmmyyyy to convert to yymmdd or yyyymmdd
- yyyymmdd to convert to ddmmyy or ddmmyyyy
- ddmmyy to convert to ddmmyyyy or ddmmyy
- yymmdd to convert to ddmmyy or ddmmyyyy

But I don’t know what format it will be passed at runtime. Is there a way to achieve this in VBA? I've created the below function that accounts for the date being of a certain length, but this will only work for 2 scenarios.

```
Function FormatDate(sDate As String, sFormat As String) As String
    Dim Y As Long, M As Long, D As Long
   
    If Len(sDate) = 6 Then
        Y = Left(sDate, 2)
        M = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
        D = Right(sDate, 2)
    Else
        Y = Left(sDate, 4)
        M = Mid(sDate, 5, 2)
        D = Right(sDate, 2)
    End If
 
    FormatDate = Format(DateSerial(Y, M, D), sFormat)
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry did a little format maybe now will be more clear so my string will be a date but just the numbers without any separation for day month and year.

Comment: It is impossible in shown conditions. `190118` may be treated as Jan 19, 2018 (ddmmyy) or Jan 18, 2019 (yymmdd) - no way to distinguish. Add source format into the parameters.

Comment: I only need the string to be manipulated as the required format so actually it’s a date but treat it as a string that needs to be various formats as required. This was the way I thought it would be easy to do but I cannot account for all scenarios as don’t know initial format at runtime.  Say for example the value is 24012020 but I need it to be 200124 format so on the function sFormat will be yymmdd but the output after the function is completely wrong as it will take the first 4 digits as the year and so on so the logic is not exactly accounting for all scenarios. Maybe there is a better way

Comment: Back up.  How is the date generated? Where is it coming from? Why is it in different formats?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thats how it’s exported from other systems and I need to import in few systems that expects certain format so regardless of what is on the sheet when constructing the api string I can pass the format that I know it works for that system.

Comment: @QuickSilver Are the **four** formats you show in *for example* the **only** possibilities?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld These 4 formats are enough for unsolvable ambiguity.

Comment: Does your data actually hold `String` data type values? Because right now you just passing them as a `String`.

Comment: @JvdV yes that column is formatted as text.

Comment: It is not possible to reliably do what you want given the rules you have proposed.  For example, the string `190523` can resolve into `19-May-2023` or `23-May-2019`.

Comment: You did not answer to the ambiguity that Akina raised, and which Ron repeats just now. Unless you can bring clarification to that, there is no solution.

Comment: What you want can be achieved but may turn out complicated unless you narrow down what kind of inputs formats you are going to receive. For example if I take into account combinations created by `d,dd,m,mm,mmm,yy,yyyy` you will get something like `dmyy,dyym,mdyy...yyyyddmmm,yyyymmmdd` approximately 71-72 combinations in total. How will you handle all those?

Comment: @trincot I see what you guys mean so there is no way as the date can be different if swapped. Basically the importing system the way it imports is based on the user profile settings so if the user has the date in format ddmmyyyy the if I try to upload a date in format yyyymmdd it will fail as it doesn’t match user profile. I thought by doing some formatting on the spreadsheet when constructing the string i’ll be able to pass different formats of the date rather than stop everything go change profile settings to match the format date on the sheet.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The user profile where I try to input the data will only have 3 settings as date input. ymd, dmy, mdy this are the accepted formats of date for input I just want a way to avoid changing profile settings and handle this options in code by formatting the string to match current profile.

Comment: Given that the user profile is unknown, there does not seem to be any way of resolving this.

Comment: What is the range of dates? Like, are there dates before 1950, 1980, 1999? Also, are there future dates, like 2021, 2025, 2030, ... Can you be specific what the maximum range is of the dates? How many dates do you have? Are they in the same column? Can you give a full example of data?

Comment: @trincot data is in one column and the date range is somewhere from 2000 to present. The number of records depends can be 10 or 1000 or more. I was thinking just swapping the year and day but then I don’t know how to account for the month being first. It seems pretty impossible now after all the chat. Format of data will be 01102020, 20201001, 011020, 201001 not aware of any date with month being first as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there can be ambiguity as to what a string like "010102" means (1 January 2002 or 2 January 2001), you could first iterate over the dates to determine which of the two interpretations works for all other dates.

Here I assume that all dates will use the *same* format. So then you can hope that there is at least one string that can only be interpreted in one way, like "000102" can only mean 2 January 2000. So if you find such an input, then you may assume other inputs are also in the yymmdd format.

For that purpose you could use this function:

```vb
Public Function GuessDateFormat(cells As Variant, minDate As Date, maxDate As Date) As String
    Dim size As Integer
    Dim cellDate As Date
    Dim dateFormat As Integer ' 0, 1 or 2
    Dim value As String

    GuessDateFormat = "inconsistent"

    size = Len(cells(1, 1).value)
    If size <> 6 And size <> 8 Then Exit Function
    For Each cell In cells
        value = cell.value
        If Len(value) <> size Then Exit Function ' Conflicting format sizes

        cellDate = DateSerial(Left(value, size - 4), Mid(value, size - 3, 2), Right(value, 2))
        If cellDate < minDate Or cellDate > maxDate Or Format(cellDate, Right("yyyymmdd", size)) <> value Then
            dateFormat = dateFormat Or 2 ' format should not be yy[yy]mmdd
        End If

        cellDate = DateSerial(Right(value, size - 4), Mid(value, 3, 2), Left(value, 2))
        If cellDate < minDate Or cellDate > maxDate Or Format(cellDate, Left("ddmmyyyy", size)) <> value Then
            dateFormat = dateFormat Or 1 ' format should not be ddmmyy[yy]
        End If

        If dateFormat = 3 Then Exit Function ' Neither format is possible
    Next
    GuessDateFormat = Array("ambiguous", Right("yyyymmdd", size), Left("ddmmyyyy", size))(dateFormat)
End Function
```

This function takes the range (column?) that has all the input strings. In addition it takes two dates, so you can help the algorithm to exclude formats when they would result in a date which you consider to be out of range.

So for instance, if your input strings are imported in the range A1:A10, and you consider that all dates should be between 1-1-2000 and today's date, then you would call the above function, from within a cell, as:

```
=GuessDateFormat(A1:A10, DATE(2000,1,1), NOW())
```

If all is well, the function will return "ddmmyy", "ddmmyyyy", "yymmdd" or "yyyymmdd". If *all* the inputs are ambiguous, and no certain choice can be made, the return value will be "ambiguous" (bad luck!).

Then you can use the following function to interpret a string as a date, given the format of the string:

```vb
Function DateFromFormat(dateString As String, srcFormat As String) As Date
    Dim dateParts(3) As String

    For i = 1 To Len(srcFormat)
        j = InStr("ymd", Mid(srcFormat, i, 1))
        If j Then dateParts(j) = dateParts(j) + Mid(dateString, i, 1)
    Next
    DateFromFormat = DateSerial(dateParts(1), dateParts(2), dateParts(3))
End Function
```

So, to expand the example, your sheet could look like this:

```
  A      |      B
---------+-----------------
19112018 | =DateFromFormat(A1, A$11)
01012002 | =DateFromFormat(A2, A$11)
02022001 | =DateFromFormat(A3, A$11)
03102005 | =DateFromFormat(A4, A$11)
04012020 | =DateFromFormat(A5, A$11)
15052019 | =DateFromFormat(A6, A$11)
19122019 | =DateFromFormat(A7, A$11)
19112019 | =DateFromFormat(A8, A$11)
20012001 | =DateFromFormat(A9, A$11)
06082006 | =DateFromFormat(A10, A$11)
=GuessDateFormat(A1:A10, DATE(2000,1,1), NOW())
```

The first column has strings, the second column has dates (make sure to format as date in Excel)

From here you can decide what to do with those dates, like formatting them to some string format you like. This you can do with the `=TEXT()` function in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

```vba
Function FormatDate(ByVal srcDate As String, ByVal srcFormat As String, ByVal dstFormat As String) As String
If Len(srcDate) <> Len(srcFormat) Then Exit Function
Dim d As String, m As String, y As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(srcDate)
    Select Case Left(srcFormat, 1)
        Case "y"
            y = y & Left(srcDate, 1)
        Case "m"
            m = m & Left(srcDate, 1)
        Case "d"
            d = d & Left(srcDate, 1)
        End Select
    srcDate = Mid(srcDate, 2)
    srcFormat = Mid(srcFormat, 2)
Next i
For i = 1 To 3
    Select Case Left(dstFormat, 2)
        Case "dd"
            FormatDate = FormatDate & d
        Case "mm"
            FormatDate = FormatDate & m
        Case "yy"
            If Left(dstFormat, 4) = "yyyy" Then
                FormatDate = FormatDate & "20" & Right(y, 2)
                dstFormat = Mid(dstFormat, 3)
            Else
                FormatDate = FormatDate & Right(y, 2)
            End If
        Case Else
            FormatDate = ""
            Exit Function
        End Select
    dstFormat = Mid(dstFormat, 3)
Next
End Function
```

```
Debug.Print FormatDate("25012019", "ddmmyyyy", "mmddyy")
Debug.Print FormatDate("25 01 2019", "dd mm yyyy", "ddmmyyyy")
' and so on ... '
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn’t work for me. On top of that on the cells I don’t have a way to tell what format is the source date string at runtime the only one I can guarantee is the destination format what is going to be. The above debug.print(formatdate(“10012020”,”ddmmyyyy”,”yyyymmdd”)) outputs 2001 where I needed it to be 20200110. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @QuickSilver Yes, a bug. Edited. *I don’t have a way to tell what format is the source date string at runtime* If so the task is unsolvable, the reason was described above. But in runtime the code which creates this source value must know how does it builds this value, is it?

Comment: still with the same example I’m getting 20202001 instead of 20200110 there is still something going wrong. But my point is still I cannot know from the spreadsheet what format will the date have unless I manually type it somewhere. I was thinking treating it like a string and not a date and just swap the date and year and should solve the problem. But in case the format will change to mmddyyyy that that will break my logic. Might as well account for any date format and make it future proof.

Comment: @QuickSilver Does you take source data from Excel worksheet where the cell have DATE datatype but custom and unknown format? If so take the DATE value, not its STRING formatted form, and format as you need...

Comment: My date is a text format in excel. Then the srcFormat is the cell value and not format form it will be the same now when I try it just outputs 20.